# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.. on build server tests

Tags: c#, entity-framework, msbuild, code-first

I use code first entity framework 6 in my project.

I have integration tests concerning my database to test it's functionality. When I run those tests locally, in VS2013 or VS2015 they all pass. Whenever I try to push my code to the build server, those same tests fail with the message - CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. I tried to manually run this code on the build server machine and when I run the tests from within visual studio 2013 they work!

The connection string to the tests database is:
`add name="MyContext.DbConnection2" provider name="System.Data.SqlClient" connection string="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test database;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=True;"`

What could be the reason that I get this error only when running build?

Comment: What credentials are the build server running under?

Comment: I think your **build server** doesn't have `SQL Express` or the **build user** doesn't have permission to create `database`

Comment: what is the user that is trying to connect

Comment: Sql express is installed on the build server. The build is using specified user, which from a look in the SQL management studio inside the server, has the same Permissions as my own user have - and the tests pass when I run them with my user manually on that server